# R-processing on a UTF-8 encoded Japanese corpus

Tags: python, r, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to process a UTF8 encoded file in Japanese.

I did the preprocessing in python, everything went OK (tokenization/collocations/stopwords) and I obtained the following kind of string:

```
リカーショップ 寄っ たら サントリー 山崎 響が 入荷_し て た
```

However, when I am trying to read the preprocessed file (a UTF-8 encoded csv) in R to run a  STM, I am getting this format :

```
<U+30AB><U+30F4><U+30A1> <U+4E00><U+676F> <U+767D> <U+8D64> <U+4E00><U+676F> <U+89D2>_<U+30CF><U+30A4><U+30DC><U+30FC><U+30EB> <U+5C71><U+5D0E> <U+30CF><U+30A4><U+30DC><U+30FC><U+30EB> <U+591A><U+304B><U+3063> <U+305F> <U+304B>
```

I first tried different import functions but with the same result :

```
df <- read.xlsx2(corpus_filename,sheetIndex=1,header=TRUE)
df <-read_csv(corpus_filename,locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

I then thought I could run the stm and go back to python to re-encode the resulting files but after half a day of trying the encode/decode functions, I have to admit that I am completely stuck.

Can anyone help me with this ?
Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
Here are the first 20 lines of the csv output of my python preprocessing (encoded in utf8) => it is the file I'm giving to my R program

```
865781289361604609;コークハイ 山崎 年 酔っ払い なう
856448528331161600;リカーショップ 寄っ たら サントリー 山崎 響が 入荷_し て た
815926577556897792;おと なしく 山崎 んどき ます w まあ 竹鶴 結局 手 にいれ まし_た しよし ます w
769384649143361536;再 来週 山崎_蒸留 所 行く アド しか_ない
860119818296414208;非売 品 山崎 仕込_み 水 水割り 最高 です_ね
759768684457975809;ゴースト 観 た 面白 かっ_た ラスト 個人_的 驚い た 最高 だろ_う こういう 時期っ て 絶対 ある よね ラスト 切り 口 俺 好き 山崎 ハイボール うまし
807576715203444736;山崎 ロック う まいわぁ
833936664938500098;ある お店 飲み_放題 ウイスキー 以前 山崎 白州 ブラックニッカ 角 変わっ てる 大人 事情っ て やつ か
744757755177664512;父 日 サントリー 山崎 プレゼント しよ_う として 円 しか なかっ_た 竹鶴 あげ た
744850084580384768;今度 山崎 か 響買 おう
742576211759628288;i サントリー 山崎_蒸溜 所 島本_町 大阪府
862666125909278720;山崎 年 だねー 杯 ご_馳走 する_よ
865932271169159172;山崎 年 神々しい
788394825494175745;山崎 年 よき て
833282834412376064;山崎_蒸留 所見 学ツアー 千円 部 大阪 ダメダメ 団 向け テイスティング
823471399289253888;おと とい 山崎 年 ごち そう なっ たん_だけ どめっっっちゃ 美味_しく て 家 帰っ_て 調べ たら 定価 でも く らい する 知っ て ヒェッ て なっ た いつも 穏やか な 愛する あまり 相手 薬漬け 快楽 漬け て 全裸 首輪 つけ て 自室 監禁 て 泣き ながら 犯す 攻め 見 た 時 よう
775381740160299008;次買う ウイスキー 山崎 しよ_う とり_あえ ず 山崎 美味い だ
862137645895262209;山崎 シェリーカスク 一 回 飲ん_でみ たいけど 値段 ぶっ 飛ん て ヤヴァイ 年 万く らい とか な
741984119035334660;山崎 ハイボール なう
768400284754190337;久々_に 自覚 する くらい 酔っ ぱらっちゃっ た ぬ 山崎 ボトル 一本 飲ませ て 頂い た よ あり たい ね
839372940374237184;ウイスキー ある_けど 家 やつ 美味_しく ない ー 山崎 響き 好き
744138456025042944;山崎 ロック 飲み_ながら 妹ちょ 見る
779968612224217089;無駄 いい ホテル 笑知っ てる と_思う けど 山崎 響飲ん だ 翌日 体臭 おじ_さん なる ね 気 をつけ て
822126367584043008;山崎 でも いい ウイスキー 蒸留_所行 き たい
753358847352246272;山崎 年 のうえ 年
```

I work under Windows 7 directly on a Rconsole by copy/pasting lines from SublimeText.

EDIT 2 :

I tried Mark's suggestion :

```
> rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
> library(readr)
> parselmouth.windows <-
+   read_delim(
+     parselmouth.csv,
+     ";",
+     escape_double = FALSE,
+     col_names = FALSE,
+     trim_ws = TRUE
+   )
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  X1 = col_double(),
  X2 = col_character()
)
> names(parselmouth.windows) <- c('document', 'content')
> parselmouth.windows$document <- as.character(parselmouth.windows$document)
>
> print.listof(head(parselmouth.windows))
document :
[1] "865781289361604608" "856448528331161600" "815926577556897792"
[4] "769384649143361536" "860119818296414208" "759768684457975808"

content :
[1] "<U+30B3><U+30FC><U+30AF><U+30CF><U+30A4> <U+5C71><U+5D0E> <U+5E74> <U+9154>
<U+3063><U+6255><U+3044> <U+306A><U+3046>"
[2] "<U+30EA><U+30AB><U+30FC><U+30B7><U+30E7><U+30C3><U+30D7> <U+5BC4><U+3063> <
U+305F><U+3089> <U+30B5><U+30F3><U+30C8><U+30EA><U+30FC> <U+5C71><U+5D0E> <U+97F
F><U+304C> <U+5165><U+8377>_<U+3057> <U+3066> <U+305F>"
[3] "<U+304A><U+3068> <U+306A><U+3057><U+304F> <U+5C71><U+5D0E> <U+3093><U+3069>
<U+304D> <U+307E><U+3059> w <U+307E><U+3042> <U+7AF9><U+9DB4> <U+7D50><U+5C40> <
U+624B> <U+306B><U+3044><U+308C> <U+307E><U+3057>_<U+305F> <U+3057><U+3088><U+30
57> <U+307E><U+3059> w"
[4] "<U+518D> <U+6765><U+9031> <U+5C71><U+5D0E>_<U+84B8><U+7559> <U+6240> <U+884
C><U+304F> <U+30A2><U+30C9> <U+3057><U+304B>_<U+306A><U+3044>"
[5] "<U+975E><U+58F2> <U+54C1> <U+5C71><U+5D0E> <U+4ED5><U+8FBC>_<U+307F> <U+6C3
4> <U+6C34><U+5272><U+308A> <U+6700><U+9AD8> <U+3067><U+3059>_<U+306D>"
[6] "<U+30B4><U+30FC><U+30B9><U+30C8> <U+89B3> <U+305F> <U+9762><U+767D> <U+304B
><U+3063>_<U+305F> <U+30E9><U+30B9><U+30C8> <U+500B><U+4EBA>_<U+7684> <U+9A5A><U
+3044> <U+305F> <U+6700><U+9AD8> <U+3060><U+308D>_<U+3046> <U+3053><U+3046><U+30
44><U+3046> <U+6642><U+671F><U+3063> <U+3066> <U+7D76><U+5BFE> <U+3042><U+308B>
<U+3088><U+306D> <U+30E9><U+30B9><U+30C8> <U+5207><U+308A> <U+53E3> <U+4FFA> <U+
597D><U+304D> <U+5C71><U+5D0E> <U+30CF><U+30A4><U+30DC><U+30FC><U+30EB> <U+3046>
<U+307E><U+3057>"
```

Comment: Encoding can be frustrating in R.  Can you 1) provide an example of the data you are trying to load?  3) Tell us what operating system you are using?  3) Tell us what R interface you are using?  For example, RStudio silently makes some encoding configurations that are usually (but not **always**) helpful/appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your advice. I edited my question. Hope it helps...

Comment: `content` has some `w` and `_`  that look like they might have been introduce during cut and paste.  Are they really in the data?

Comment: @GRW yes they are. "w" might be a typo or an abbreviation or anything. "_" is a notation I've introduced to paste together most frequent bigrams.

Answer (score 2):

Right, I suspected you were using Windows.  In Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.2, RStudio 0.99.879, R 3.3.2), reading and printing **just works**.

```
parselmouth.ubuntu <-
  read.csv('parselmouth.csv', header = FALSE, sep = ";")

> head(parselmouth.ubuntu)
            V1
1 8.657813e+17
2 8.564485e+17
3 8.159266e+17
4 7.693846e+17
5 8.601198e+17
6 7.597687e+17
                                                                                                                                               V2
1                                                                                                                コークハイ 山崎 年 酔っ払い なう
2                                                                                     リカーショップ 寄っ たら サントリー 山崎 響が 入荷_し て た
3                                                                   おと なしく 山崎 んどき ます w まあ 竹鶴 結局 手 にいれ まし_た しよし ます w
4                                                                                                        再 来週 山崎_蒸留 所 行く アド しか_ない
5                                                                                                     非売 品 山崎 仕込_み 水 水割り 最高 です_ね
6 ゴースト 観 た 面白 かっ_た ラスト 個人_的 驚い た 最高 だろ_う こういう 時期っ て 絶対 ある よね ラスト 切り 口 俺 好き 山崎 ハイボール うまし
>
```

I think you'll find that internally, R **for Windows** does "know" the correct encoding of your data.  It's just not being printed in a way we would expect or hope for.

I recommend reading http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~izahn/posts/reading-data-with-non-native-encoding-in-r/

Try saving your example data as `parselmouth.csv`, installing the `readr` library, and then running

```
library(readr)
parselmouth.windows <-
  read_delim(
    "parselmouth.csv",
    ";",
    escape_double = FALSE,
    col_names = FALSE,
    trim_ws = TRUE
  )

names(parselmouth.windows) <- c('document', 'content')
parselmouth.windows$document <- as.character(parselmouth.windows$document)

print.listof(head(parselmouth.windows))
```

And you will see:

```
document :
[1] "865781289361604608" "856448528331161600" "815926577556897792"
[4] "769384649143361536" "860119818296414208" "759768684457975808"

content :
[1] "コークハイ 山崎 年 酔っ払い なう"                                                                                                               
[2] "リカーショップ 寄っ たら サントリー 山崎 響が 入荷_し て た"                                                                                    
[3] "おと なしく 山崎 んどき ます w まあ 竹鶴 結局 手 にいれ まし_た しよし ます w"                                                                  
[4] "再 来週 山崎_蒸留 所 行く アド しか_ない"                                                                                                       
[5] "非売 品 山崎 仕込_み 水 水割り 最高 です_ね"                                                                                                    
[6] "ゴースト 観 た 面白 かっ_た ラスト 個人_的 驚い た 最高 だろ_う こういう 時期っ て 絶対 ある よね ラスト 切り 口 俺 好き 山崎 ハイボール うまし"
```

If there's still no joy, it may be helpful to determine or set the current locale.  In my Windows example, I'm using the default windows codepage:

```
Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

But I could change it

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.932")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.932;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.932;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.932"
```

You could also use a hex editor to verify that your input is the same as mine:

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I stumbled across your link already during my research but applying it didn't work. As for your bit of code, I ran it but the result is still the same. I do not care about the terminal screen but I would really like a clean export. Do you think I could use a conversion step after the processing ?

Comment: Well, it's a good weblink, but it's not "mine."  Can you give me some details about getting the **same** result?  I just pasted the code into a R 3.2.2 console in Windows 10 and got the output as Japanese characters.  Did you paste my suggested commands exactly?  Maybe the way we saved/encoded the input file makes a difference.  I cut from your post, pasted into notepad++, and saved. I don't think I did any customization to notepad++, and I would assume that sublime would behave the same.

Comment: @Parselmouthintraining You say that you want "a clean export".  Do you just want to write it out to a text file or something else?

Comment: I edited my question with the content of my R console. Regarding the way we saved the document, I tried both with the original and a copy/pasted version and the result is the same. Maybe I should try to download Notepad++, just to be sure ...

Comment: @G5W I use R to run a stm on the Japanese corpus. So I would like the final results (topics, graphs and annotated corpus=> xlsx file) to be readable (so check-able) by native speakers.

Comment: @G5W I already tried to run the stm and export the processed corpus in a xlsx file but it is encoded the same way than the Rconsole... that's why I was thinking of a separate "conversion" script (inelegant but desperate) ?

Comment: just for a temporary reality check, would you be willing to install an Ubuntu Virtual Box?  And then install R within the virtual Ubuntu machine?  You would have to move your input file in there.  So it's a little up front work, but it would eliminate the need for an after the fact conversion.

Comment: Using @MarkMiller 's original read.csv statement did not work for me under Windows,  but a slight modification _did_ work. What worked for me was `TestData = read.csv("Test.txt", sep=";", encoding="UTF-8",
  header=FALSE, colClasses=c("character", "character"))`  As Mark noted, display of this under Windows is not quite right.  Please try displaying `TestData$content` not the whole data.frame,  or use his suggested `print.listof(TestData)`

Comment: @G5W right, that `read.csv` command isn't expected to "just work" in Windows.  Only Unix-like OSes.  The `read.csv` command you just added is a good WIndows solution.

Comment: Thank you both for your solutions. The display/export are still the same with G5W's solution. So I tried to make it work on my personal machine (Ubuntu) and it worked perfectly fine (except for the automatic export from the stm module but that I hope I will manage to write substitutes). Unfortunately, I can't install a virtual Box on my professional machine... so I guess I will resume my research !

Comment: Mmm, frustrating!  Have you checked your R locale or examined the data file with a text editor?  Could you try this on a different Windows machine?